# Why separate vendor CSS & JS from custom CSS & JS in a workflow?

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, bower, frontend, yeoman

I've been trying to determine the reasoning behind what seems to have become the standard practice in Front End workflows of separating vendor JS & CSS from custom JS & CSS. I'm not sure what the benefits are over the disadvantage of an extra HTTP request, it would seem cleaner to just have a single CSS & JS file rather than having vendor.css, main.css & vendor.js, main.js.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: I think that would be interesting.  Maybe have a new file type like .jcross or jcss.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vendor code typically changes less frequently than your application's code. Thus as you update your application, the vendor code can remain unchanged and cached in your user's browser.

In the scenario where vendor code is bundled with application code, the user has to download all of the vendor code every time you update the application.

The extra HTTP request from the separate vendor bundle is mitigated by the fact that the user will download less code on each application update.

Comment: Thank you for you answers, I've deemed Sunil's as correct as his explanation was the clearest for me

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two reasons.

1. Hosting vendor code separately from your code (e.g. [Google Hosted Libraries](https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/))
2. Separation of concerns: the vendor code might be large and is updated independently of your custom code. Maintaining your code in a separate file avoids the need to put vendor code into your source control, makes it easier to navigate your code, makes it easy to upgrade to new vendor code since you know for certain the vendor code has not been tweaked.

Especially since you tagged the question with `grunt`, the end user might never see this change since you can merge vendor and user styles/scripts during the build.

However, if vendor code is large and changes infrequently, you do get a caching benefit from having a rarely changing, large vendor file accompanied by a small, fast changing custom code file. For large sites that do not use a CDN (hopefully, not yours), the impact can be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your situation, this allows you to make your edits lower in the cascade so you can override vendor styles and behaviors without blowing away their code. This is helpful so that you always have a working version(vendor code) you can revert to. In situations like working with Wordpress, developing a child theme allows the parent theme to be updated without blowing away your customizations.

Comment: I'm thinking less in terms of Wordpress and more interms of Frontend Generators i.e. Yeoman as Gulp/Grunt plugins tend to lean towards the seperation of JS & CSS. Interms of the overriding you would combine your Custom JS/CSS after the Vendor CSS/JS as you would embed in your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Various answers already addressed this but i'll make it very specific:

1. Vendor code might change more or less frequently than your code.  If
   vendor code changes more frequently, e.g. for bug fixes, you would
   want to use the newer versions and have a better overall website. 
   If vendor code changes LESS frequently than your code, you may wish
   to change your code w/o touching working stuff.
2. Vendor code is often hosted on CDNs, for example https://cdnjs.com/#q=ajax or
   https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/  These are FAST
   loading.  They also wont change, so the user can rely on cached
   files and thus your website will load up faster.
3. It is generally better to make iterative changes to code.  It is also easier to manage code, esp with source control when specific
   things are changing.  No need to swap large files when they have not
   changed.  Keeping things separate makes it easier to make
   incremental changes, esp if the two things have different change
   velocities.